# Is it better to log to file or database?

Tags: sql-server, logging, asp-classic

We're still using old Classic ASP and want to log whenever a user does something in our application. We'll write a generic subroutine to take in the details we want to log.

Should we log this to, say, a txt file using `FileSystemObject` or log it to a MS SQL database?

In the database, should we add a new table to the one existing database or should we use a separate database?

Comment: I suppose a local database that sits on the filesystem of the local machine is not an option? You can always export the records you want to the central database later.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Edit**

In hindsight, a better answer is to log to *BOTH* file system (first, immediately) and then to a centralized database (even if delayed). Most modern logging frameworks follow a `publish-subscribe` model (often called logging sources and sinks) which will allow multiple logging sinks (targets) to be defined.

The rationale behind writing to file system that if an external infrastructure dependency like network, database, or security issue prevents you from writing remotely, that at least you have a fall back if you can recover data from the server's hard disk (something akin to a black box in the airline industry). Log data written to a file system  can be deleted as soon as it is confirmed that the central database has recorded the data, so generally file system retention sizes or rotation times need not be large.

Enterprise log managers like [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) can be configured to scrape your local server log files (e.g. as written by `log4net`, the EntLib `Logging Application Block`, et al) and then centralize them in a searchable database, where data logged can be mined, graphed, shown on dashboards, etc.

But from an operational perspective, where it is likely that you will have a farm or cluster of servers, and assuming that both the local file system and remote database logging mechanisms are working, the 99% use case for actually trying to find anything in a log file will still be via the central database (ideally with a decent front end system to allow you to query, aggregate, graph and build triggers or notifications from log data).

**Original Answer**

If you have the database in place, I would recommend using this for audit records instead of the filesystem.

**Rationale:**

- typed and normalized classification of data (`severity, action type, user, date ...`)
- it is easier to find audit data (`select ... from Audits where ...` ) vs Grep
- it is easier to clean up (e.g. `Delete from Audits where = Date ...`)
- it is easier to back up

The decision to use existing db or new one depends - if you have multiple applications (with their own databases) and want to log / audit all actions in all apps centrally, then a centralized db might make sense.

Since you say you want to audit user activity, it may would make sense to audit in the same db as your users table / definition (if applicable).

Comment: Totally agree - I've done it both ways and for the most part dislike reading through log files.  By putting the log entries into something that can be queried, you can do some trend analysis (e.g. what kind of exceptions / entries are on the rise, what errors are happening most often, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I'll go down this route. Just the one app so will use a new table in the same DB.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with the above with the perhaps obvious exception of logging database failures which would make logging to the database problematic.  This has come up for me in the past as I was dealing with infrequent but regular network failovers.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm looking to log stuff like what user has delete what anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Either works.  It's up to your preference.

We have one central database where ALL of our apps log their error messages.  Every app we write is set up in a table with a unique ID, and the error log table contains a foreign key reference to the AppId.

This has been a HUGE bonus for us in giving us one place to monitor errors.  We had done it as a file system or by sending emails to a monitored inbox in the past, but we were able to create a fairly nice web app for interacting with the error logs.  We have different error levels, and we have an "acknowledged" flag field, so we have a page where we can view unacknowledged events by severity, etc.,

Comment: Thanks David, just the one app so will use the same DB

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the responses, I think the answer may actually be both.

If it's a user error that's likely to happen during expected usage (e.g. user enters an invalid email etc.), that should go into a database to take advantage of easy queries.

If it's a code error that shouldn't happen (can't get username of a logged in user), that should be reserved for a txt file.

This also nicely splits the errors between non-critical and critical. Hopefully the critical error list stays small!

I'm creating a quick prototype of a new project right now, so I'll stick with txt for now.

On another note, email is great for this. Arguably you could just email them to a "bug" account and not store them locally. However this shares the database risk of bad connections.

Comment: why not log like crazy? logging is not exclusively for exceptional states but when an exceptional state arises you don't know what might happen.  It'd be frustrating if a whole bunch of user errors got lost because of a dbase problem.  Equally, why not bung code errors in the dbase as well as a text file... for all the dbase-related benefits.

Comment: @mikerodent Sure but I think it's a good idea to create clear separations based on the type and severity of errors. E.g. I think you wouldn't want to store DB crash logs in the same place as failed login attempts.

Answer (score 0):

> Should we log this to say a txt file using FileSystemObject or log it
>   to a MSSQL database?

Another idea is to write the log file in XML and then query it using XPath. I like to think that this is the best of both worlds.

Comment: Make it even better, log in a file using json :D

Comment: The worst of both worlds: The logs grow a lot and the queries will never be nowhere as fast as the DB.